# (V4L2: /dev/video0) can't open camera by index

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, nvidia-jetson, jetson-xavier

I have an error on my algorithm with Jetson Xavier NX. I try to run code but terminal say that :

> [ WARN:0] global /home/arc/opencv_build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "realtime_quadrant.py", line 41, in 
> height = frame.shape
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

This means that I have to change 0 in camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0).

So I try

```
cv2.VideoCapture(1), 
cv2.VideoCapture(-1) 
cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

yet I still have the same error.  Also I installed V4l2 ( Sudo apt-get install v4l2) How can I do that to run?

Comment: Please, give the results of the command 
```ls /dev | grep video```

Comment: @RabiaTüylek which camera type are you using? Note that [CSI cameras based on OV5647 sensor are not supported](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/does-jetson-nano-support-csi-camera-with-sensor-ov5647/74911)

Comment: Camera that I use https://openzeka.com/urun/li-pi-ipex-1233-adpt/. What should do I ?

Comment: @RabiaTüylek you can see this [repo](https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/CSI-Camera)

Comment: I write 'ls /dev | grep video' on command but it did not say anything.

Comment: You may tell more about the camera you're trying to use. Is it a CSI or USB camera ? What sensor, what model ? Do you have installed SDK that may include driver, device-tree, maybe firmware ?